# How to show and hide Android Edit Text Preference?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, edittextpreference

I just wish to know how can i show or hide  edit text preference that i use to add username and password.

can i use such kind of feature here  -to enable or disable a button in xml for edit text preference as well

> ImageButton ready = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ready);
>
> ready.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>
> ```
> <EditTextPreference
>     android:key="password"
>     android:title="@string/pref_title_password"
>     android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_password"
>     android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
>     android:inputType="textPassword"
>     android:capitalize="words"
>     android:singleLine="true"
>     android:maxLines="1" />
> ```

Comment: Doing so in xml? tricky. but i could suggest the same in the context code be it; activity, service e.t.c.

Comment: can i use something like that in code for edittextpreference   ImageButton ready = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ready);

                            mic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: That is it, if you would like to make it invisible or cover it with another view or disable it or create it programmatically in java after your conditions are satisfied. I think it would only make sense in the context code.

Comment: can you help me how to do that .. dont find any referene online ... how to hide

Answer (score 0):

`EditTextPreference` is not derived from `android.view.View`, therefore `setVisibilty` will not work. Instead do as follows:-

get the underlying `EditText`.

call `setVisibility` from there. Or proceed further by getting the parent view and calling the method from there.

Compiling our explanation, yield should be as follows:-

**get the preference:-**

```java
EditTextPreference pswd=(EditTextPreference)findPreference("password");
```

**then:-**

```java
pswd.getEditText().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**or generally:-**

```java
ViewParent parent=pswd.getEditText().getParent();
if(parent instanceof View)
((View)parent).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else pswd.getEditText().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**Edit:**
The method `findPreference` is found in [`android.preference.PreferenceActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) or [`android.preference.PreferenceFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment).
Which means you need to call it from a fragment or activity that is derived from any of them - Your activity should extend any of them.

I have not tested the above snippets yet but feel free to edit correction or comment.

Comment: i am getting this error : cannot find symbol method findPreference(String)     Any help would be highly appreciated